# Beans added dynamically are not considered by ConditionalOnBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am registering beans dynamically at startup with `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`:

Bean class:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DynamicBean {

    private final String name;
    private final Object value;

}
```

Properties class:

```java
@Data
public class DynamicProperties {
    private List<Bean> beans;

    @Data
    public static class Bean {
        private String name;
        private Object value;
    }
}
```

`BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`:

```java
@Configuration
public class DynamicBeanRegistrar implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry beanDefinitionRegistry) throws BeansException {
        DynamicProperties dynamicProperties = Binder.get(environment)
                .bind("dynamic", Bindable.of(DynamicProperties.class))
                .orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);

        dynamicProperties.getBeans().forEach(bean -> {
            GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
            beanDefinition.setBeanClass(DynamicBean.class);

            String beanName = bean.getName();

            ConstructorArgumentValues cav = new ConstructorArgumentValues();
            cav.addGenericArgumentValue(bean.getName());
            cav.addGenericArgumentValue(bean.getValue());
            beanDefinition.setConstructorArgumentValues(cav);

            beanDefinitionRegistry.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, beanDefinition);
            log.info("Registered dynamic bean")
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory) throws BeansException {
        // noop
    }
}
```

I also have another configuration class using `@ConditionalOnBean` annotation for some beans:

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class AnotherConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Object a() {
        return new Object ();
    }

    @Bean
    public Object b() {
        return new Object ();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnBean(DynamicBean.class)
    public Object x() {
        return new Object();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnBean(DynamicBean.class)
    public Object y() {
        return new Object();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `@ConditionalOnBean` annotation doesn't seem to know about the dynamically registered beans and is therefore evaluating as false, causing beans x and y not to be created.
I have tried using `@AutoConfigureBefore(AnotherConfiguration.class)` on my `DynamicBeanRegistrar` as well as implementing `PriorityOrdered`, but that didn't seem to have any effect.

Is there any way to achieve the expected behavior?

Comment: Have you tried using `@DependsOn` on `AnotherConfiguration` so that it depends on `DynamicBeanRegistrar`?

Comment: @JoãoDias thanks for your answer. Just tried that and it has no effect. Still the same behaviour

Answer (score 0):

As per [the JavaDoc of Condition](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Condition.html):

> Conditions are checked immediately before the bean-definition is due
> to be registered and are free to veto registration based on any
> criteria that can be determined at that point.

`BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor::postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry` is being called after all beans have been registered, thus after evaluating conditions. Consequently, all beans added dynamically are not considered during the evaluation of conditions.

The same can happen for non-dynamic beans if a bean's definition is registered before the definition of the bean to which a condition refers. For that reason, it's strongly recommended to use  `@ConditionalOnBean`, `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`, and `@ConditionalOnSingleCandidate` annotations on auto-configuration classes only, according to [the JavaDoc](https://The%20condition%20can%20only%20match%20the%20bean%20definitions%20that%20have%20been%20processed%20by%20the%20application%20context%20so%20far%20and,%20as%20such,%20it%20is%20strongly%20recommended%20to%20use%20this%20condition%20on%20auto-configuration%20classes%20only.%20If%20a%20candidate%20bean%20may%20be%20created%20by%20another%20auto-configuration,%20make%20sure%20that%20the%20one%20using%20this%20condition%20runs%20after.):

> The condition can only match the bean definitions that have been processed by the application context so far and, as such, it is strongly recommended to use this condition on auto-configuration classes only. If a candidate bean may be created by another auto-configuration, make sure that the one using this condition runs after.

---

As a workaround, bean definitions can be added or removed in `postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry` based on a condition, but I'd not recommend it since it can result in unexpected behavior.

For example, if a bean's definition is added in `postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry` there might be conditions referenced to that bean or its type processed before.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have `@ConditionalOnBean` in my custom starter. I needed to create a list of beans in the service, which based on a property file.
So I fix this problem like this.

```
public class MyDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor
    implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor, PriorityOrdered, EnvironmentAware {

  public static final String PROPERTY_PREFIX = "prefix";

  private Environment environment;

  @Override
  public void setEnvironment(final Environment env) {
    environment = env;
  }

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry)
      throws BeansException {
    getProperties(environment).getData().stream()
        .map(CacheData::getConfig)
        .forEach(
            cacheConfig -> {
              registry.registerBeanDefinition(`your bean definition register here`);
            });
  }

  @Override
  public int getOrder() {
    return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
  }

  private MyCofigurationProperties getProperties(Environment environment) {
    BindResult<MyCofigurationProperties> result =
        Binder.get(environment).bind(PROPERTY_PREFIX, MyCofigurationProperties.class);
    return result.get();
  }

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory)
      throws BeansException {}
}
```

And after this add this `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(App.class, MyDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.class)
...

  }
}
```